# XAML ComboBox Item string too long - can it be transferred to next row?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, combobox

I am developing windows phone application (XAML/C# based).
So I have a `ComboBox` control thats contains `Items` as string from database.
I noticed that when there is more items, the ComboBox stretch itself on the whole device screen that is OK, but the problem is when item string is too long 
it is cut off.

[image]

So may question is how can the string be transferred to the next line, and the item remains whole (1 item on 2 rows).

My Second question is how can I add line separators between the items?

Here is my XAML ComboBox code:

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Margin="0,49,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="193"
    PlaceholderText="Choose" 
    SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged"/>
```

I am adding the items like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if (!ComboBox.Items.Contains(item[i].item_name))
    {
        ComboBox.Items.Add(item[i].item_name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `TextBlock` it has a property named `TextWrapping`. But to use it you will have to define `ComboBox.ItemTemplate`.

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="ComboBox" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
    Margin="0,49,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Width="193"
    PlaceholderText="Choose" 
    SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">

    <!-- Template Start -->
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock 
            Text="{item_name}" 
            TextWrapping="Wrap" />      <!-- it will wrap the text -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <!-- Template End -->

</ComboBox>
```